# SQLite convert milliseconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sqlite

based on the SQLite documentation, there is time() that is equivalent with  strftime('%H:%M:%S', ...). SO i tested it with my query

```
time(time)
```

but after run the query, all the result become 12:00:00

the data is basically in milliseconds (25000, 5000, 15000)

What is the problem??

Comment: Are you putting in time(25000, 5000, 15000)? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The [built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) interpret numbers as Julian day numbers, unless you use the `unixepoch` modifier to specify seconds:

```
SELECT time(time / 1000, 'unixepoch');
```